# How to get only nonzero values from Sparse Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Utilizing TensorFlow's HashTable lookup implementation i get my SparseTensor back with the default value supplied.  I'd like to clean that off and get a final SparseTensor without the default value.

How can I clean that default value? I don't mind what the default value will be in order to make this happen.  0 is fine and so is -1.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.sparse_retain` should work:

```
def sparse_remove(sparse_tensor, remove_value=0.):
  return tf.sparse_retain(sparse_tensor, tf.not_equal(a.values, remove_value))
```

As an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[1, 2], [2, 2]], values=[0., 1.], shape=[3, 3])
with tf.Session() as session:
  print(session.run([a, sparse_remove(a)]))
```

Prints (I've reformatted it slightly):

```
[SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[1, 2], [2, 2]]), values=array([ 0.,  1.], dtype=float32), shape=array([3, 3])), 
 SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[2, 2]]), values=array([ 1.], dtype=float32), shape=array([3, 3]))]
```